# Device Emulator Smartface failed to lauch on device

Tags: smartface.io

I am using USB connection for device emulator and when the app installs on my device and when I run the app on device message comes " Unfortunately Smartface Has Stop  Responding" I have tried many times but it fails.

Thanks 
Manthan Shah

Comment: Can you try to open an empty project, does it work on your device?

Comment: empty project does work but not on project I am working on.@mervebıçakçı

Comment: do you use repeatbox object in your project, there was a bug case about this object. If you are using a repeatbox object, can you please try to delete it, and test again.

Comment: no I am not using repeatbox I amd only using textbox and buttons @mervebıçakçı

Comment: I guess there is some script errors, can you please use "All syntax check" button. If this doesn't show you any errors, then can you share the script of Page1(main page of the application) and also Global.Smartface.js. Although there is a script error, application should not give this kind of error, but I am trying to understand the cause of this error.

Comment: I can't Paste the whole code here but if you can give me your mail id I will send you the code so you can test. @mervebıçakçı

Comment: You can send to merve.bicakci@smartface.io

Comment: did sent you Please download @mervebıçakçı

Comment: Manthan, can you check your mail please.

Comment: @mervebıçakçı Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size its 9.81mb file.